# Devise: How to override devise error messages on password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How can I customize error messages to override devise passwords controller?

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(params[resource_name])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :send_instructions) if is_navigational_format?
      respond_with resource, :location => home_path
    else
      binding.pry
      flash[:devise_password_error] =  (resource.errors.map do |key, value|
        value.capitalize
      end).flatten.join('|')
      redirect_to home_path and return
    end
  end
  def edit
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
  end
end
```

resource.errors is available in this method but it contains default messages such as `Email not found` and `Email can't be blank`. i need to customize this messages. I've tried to remove `:validatable` from my user model and add custom validators but this works only for my custom registrations controller derived from Devise::RegistrationsController and not for custom passwords controller.

Is there any solution?

Comment: I know this is old, but check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18578028/1964165) for a more generic and clean approach.

Answer (score 18):

The answer is to modify **config/locales/devise.en.yml** but you must add the settings, they are not there by default.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:
              confirmation: "does not match"
              too_short: "is too short (minimum is %{count} characters)"
```

Credit for this goes to Vimsha who answered virtually the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530682/modify-devise-reset-password-error-text/20531038#20531038) for me.

Comment: You should use %{count} in the error message rather than hard coding the minimum value. count is passed to I18n.t by the range validator, and therefore will always match the devise setting.

Answer (score 9):

Devise messages are located in **config/locales/devise.en.yml**

I'm not sure which message you're trying to override, but that's where you want to do that.

Comment: The messages i want to override are not located there. These message i want to change are default messages used when validation fails and `config/locales/devise.en.yml` contains devise information messages.

Comment: Those messages are indeed not in there, but you can add them and it will work. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but based on [this related ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101641/rails-devise-handling-devise-error-messages) I've got it working with the following (which I know is a bit of a hack, but it works):

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
     resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| msg == 'Email not found' ? 'The email address you entered could not be found. Please try again with other information.' : msg }.join('<br/>')
  end
end
```

Put this in a module called `devise_helper.rb` in your `/app/helpers` directory

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: 'passwords' }
```

or

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => 'passwords' }
```