# Modify Devise reset password error text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using the Devise GEM, when a user password is reset they are allowed to set a new password. If the entered passwords do not match or if the password is too short, you get default messages:

> •Password doesn't match confirmation
>
> •Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)

How/where can I change the text of these error messages?

Comment: look at config/locals/en.yml https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml

Comment: actually the messages you want aren't there look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330821/how-to-override-devise-error-messages-on-password-change

Comment: Yep, the messages shown are actually from activerecord as the accepted answer shows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this to your config/locals/en.yml and change it to what you want

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:
              confirmation: "Password does not match"
              too_short: "is too short (minimum is %{count} characters)"
    attributes:
      user:
        password: "Password"
```

Comment: the resulting message for this is "Password Password does not match" ... Where is the first word coming from? I ask because I want to change it to "Passwords do not match" (plural)

Comment: You should use %{count} in the error message rather than hard coding the minimum value. count is passed to I18n.t by the range validator, and therefore will always match the devise setting.