# Change Devise Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb

In my application.html.erb file I have

```
<% flash.each do |key,msg| %>
    <div class="message" id="<%= key %>">
        <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

which shows all the notices. Is there a way to add Devise's error be viewed in that notice?

Also, is there a way I can edit the HTML code when there is an error.

When there is an error, it adds a div with an id `field_with_errors` — can I change that?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839071/customizing-devise-error-messages-in-rails-3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what your looking for, but the `config/locales/devise.en.yml` allows you to change the content of the messages.

Comment: I don't want to change the text, just the HTML output like change and ID or add a class, etc

Answer (score 0):

`rails generate devise:views` will copy Devise's views to your app so you can edit them freely.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Comment: I've done that, it doesn't allow you to change the HTML of the errors though.