# Devise Custom Error Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongoid

I know that you can use the devise.en.yml locale to set custom error messages but message like "Password can't be blank" or "Email can't be blank" aren't in the locale to be customized. Is there anyway to change those?

After reading I found that I can use:

```
en:
  mongoid:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "custom invalid message"
```

But now the message reads "Email custom invalid message". How come the name of the field is added to the beginning of the custom message? Is there anyway to change this behavior?

Comment: Have you considered forking devise from github? There are already more than 2000 forks, maybe one of them aleady does this.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: It can be usefull: [Customizing Devise error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839071/customizing-devise-error-messages-in-rails-3)

Comment: @drinor thanks I found your answer useful, I updated my question with a concern about it, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
en:
  mongoid:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: 'Your name for email'
```

'user' is the model and 'email' the field you want to translate.

Comment: Great this works, how can i also add to this to provide a custom message if the email field is blank?