# Rails Devise how to customize error message for specific page / action?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I currently new to Ruby on Rails 5 and using Devise 4.7.1

My question is, how do I customize the **Email not found** message validation error on forgot password page?

For example change the error message from **Email not found** to "You are not registered yet. Please contact our ABC company"

[image]

I know I can customize the language at devise.en.yml, but this will effected global message. I just want to customize the error message for that specific page only

[image: devise.en.yml]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

locales/en.yml

```
activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              not_found: "You are not registered yet. Please contact our ABC company"
```

Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18578028/417899